# How to pass matrix columns as parameters to an .apply function?

Tags: r, apply

I want to pass multiple parameters at once to a function, where these parameters are vectors contained in a matrix like this one:

```
> head(M, 3)
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.3709584  1.304870 -0.3066386
[2,] -0.5646982  2.286645 -1.7813084
[3,]  0.3631284 -1.388861 -0.1719174
```

For example considering `cor()` the following line gives me what I want, but I don't want nesting.

```
> sapply(1:3, function(x) sapply(1:3, function(y, ...) cor(M[, x], M[, y])))
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.0000000 -0.3749289  0.4400510
[2,] -0.3749289  1.0000000 -0.1533438
[3,]  0.4400510 -0.1533438  1.0000000
```

I thought `outer()` would be a candidate, since:

```
> outer(1:3, 1:3, function(x, y) x + y)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
[2,]    3    4    5
[3,]    4    5    6
```

But

```
corFun <- function(x, y) cor(M[, x], M[, y])
outer(1:3, 1:3, corFun)
```

won't work. `mapply(corFun, M[, 1], M[, 2])` attempts won't work either.

I want to do `xFun(corFun, M, arg)` or even better `xFun(cor, M, arg)` that gives (like above):

```
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.0000000 -0.3749289  0.4400510
[2,] -0.3749289  1.0000000 -0.1533438
[3,]  0.4400510 -0.1533438  1.0000000
```

where `arg <- combn(1:3, 2)` or `arg <- t(expand.grid(1:3, 1:3))`.

Generally I'm wondering if there's an **existing base R function** something like `xFun(FUN, ..., arg)` that passes a parameter matrix `arg` with `dim(arg)[1] == 2` column-wise to a function `FUN = function(x, y)`, or, perhaps, even more generally `dim(arg)[1] == length(formals(FUN))`.

---

***Data:***

```
set.seed(42)
M <- matrix(rnorm(30), 10, 3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`outer` is your function but you just need to `Vectorize` your `corfun`

```
outer(1:3, 1:3, Vectorize(corFun))
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,]  1.0000000 -0.3749289  0.4400510
#[2,] -0.3749289  1.0000000 -0.1533438
#[3,]  0.4400510 -0.1533438  1.0000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be `combn`

```
combn(1:3, m = 3, FUN = corFun)[,, 1]
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,]  1.0000000 -0.3749289  0.4400510
#[2,] -0.3749289  1.0000000 -0.1533438
#[3,]  0.4400510 -0.1533438  1.0000000
```

The result however is an array, hence the `[,, 1]`.